# iOS NSURLConnection with NSURL with https:// is using TLS or SSL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, https

If I am using `NSURLConnection` with `NSURL` like `https://www.example.com`in iOS app(given that my server `www.example.com` is TLS enabled and SSL disabled), I am using SSL or TLS?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/whats-the-difference-between-ssl-tls-and-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client supplies a list of protocols to a server to use, the server picks one it supports.
This is in general.

You do not supply enough information to answer your question. What iOS version you use?

Here is an excerpt from Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2287/_index.html).

iOS 5's TLS implementation has been upgraded to support TLS protocol version 1.2. Some non-compliant TLS server implementations do not implement TLS 1.2 and, more importantly, do not downgrade gracefully to a supported protocol version. As a result you may find that some TLS client applications built against the iOS 5 SDK may not connect to some TLS servers, when the same application built against a previous version of the iOS SDK would connect.

You may try configure the TLS protocol version using the TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol and TLSMaximumSupportedProtocol properties of the configuration. However with NSURLConnection the control over sockets is limited, e.g. you can't control ciphers, see [this discussion](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2014/Jul/msg00072.html).

You may want to use Wireshark to see what is being used in your case.

Comment: currently, I am using iOS 6,7,8 for my app. so it be able to use TLS 1.2 right?

Comment: Yes, it should be able.